# Complex Numbers (Modulus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

The complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ are given by $$z_1=5+i,z_2=2-3i$$

Find the modulus of $z_1-z_2$

My attempt,

modulus of $z_1-z_2=\sqrt{5^2+1^2}-\sqrt{2^2+3^2}$

$=\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{13}$

$=\sqrt{13}$

But the given answer is 5. Why? Am I wrong?

Comment: You just calculated $|z_1| - |z_2|$ which is not necessarily the same thing as $|z_1 - z_2|$

Comment: Not every operation is linear.  In particular $|z_1 -z_2| \ne |z_1|-|z_2|$ in general and $\sqrt{x-y} \ne \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$ in general.

Comment: In particular, that reasoning would mean that the modulus of $z_2-z_1$ is negative....

Comment: see what happens if $z_2=  -z_1?$

Comment: Also $\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{13}\ne\sqrt{13}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|z_1 - z_2| = |5 + i - 2 + 3i| = |3 + 4i| = \sqrt{3^2+4^2} = \sqrt{25} = 5$

note: $|z_1 - z_2|$ is in general different than $|z_1| - |z_2|$  (only equal if their arguments are the same and $|z_1|>|z_2|$)

Answer (score 2):

$z_1-z_2=(5+i)-(2-3i)=3+4i$

Hence $|z_1 - z_2| = |3 + 4i| =\sqrt{3^2+4^2} =\sqrt{9+16}=\sqrt{25} = 5$

But you've calculated $|z_1| - |z_2|$ not $|z_1 - z_2|$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find $w=z_1-z_2$ and then find the modulus of $w$. This is because modulus is in general non-linear.

Following [this](http://suitcaseofdreams.net/Properties_modulus.htm) link showcases the fact that
$$|z_1-z_2|\ge |z_1|-|z_2|.$$

Comment: What do you think the odds are that the OP is helped at all by the word "non-linear?"

Comment: Well, the triangle inequality is a solid example of my point.

Comment: Sigh, so you tell him it is non-linear, and when I ask you why you'd expect him to know what that means, you say this thing you just told him is non-linear is explanation enough? Nope.